# .htaccess custom 503 page won't work

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-503

First 3 Lines of my .htaccess file look like that:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /wartung/404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /wartung/404.html
ErrorDocument 503 /wartung/503.html
```

While 403 and 404 work out 503 still shows the old Server default Message. Files are all in the right directory. Also when i use Firebug i and click on the Network Request which results in 503 the "Answer" Tab shows my new 503 page but the browser windows shows the old one?

Any ideas about that? Server is some linux with apache 2.

Thanks in advance,

i3

Comment: What is the triggering condition for the Service Unavailable error? If something is happening to the server or the file system, it is possible that execution is not reaching the custom rule you are setting, so the default error message is being shown.

Comment: Can the default one be changed in the httpd.conf? The condition would be capacity Problems i guess. Some php process are stacking up till high in the sky due some problems with a soap connection.

Comment: I would try that, yes, putting it outside any virtual host sections.

Comment: Hey Wige, that one works fine. Defining the ErrorDocument in httpd.conf solves this Problem. Thanks alot. Path has to be relative to the document root i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this isn't just some caching problem in your local browser? Have you tried clearing your cache and reloading the page?

Comment: I have my browser cache alwayes deactivated. I will check again next time Server goes down. Does not happen so often.